# combining a names array with the values array in object es6

Tags: javascript

I'm using the influxdata API and that data comes back in this format:

```
{
  "columns": [
    "time", 
    "commit_time", 
    "expiration_time", 
    "kafka_consumer_group", 
    "kafka_offset_group", 
    "kafka_topic", 
    "kafka_topic_parition", 
    "message_metadata"
  ], 
  "name": "offsets", 
  "values": [
    [
      "2017-04-01T22:51:50.301Z", 
      "1491087110301", 
      "1491173510301", 
      "group-general-service-master", 
      0, 
      "replica-conversion-dev", 
      "6", 
      "NO_METADATA"
    ], 
    [
      "2017-04-01T22:51:50.301Z", 
      "1491087110301", 
      "1491173510301", 
      "group-message-service-master", 
      2, 
      "service-dev", 
      "4", 
      "NO_METADATA"
    ], 
    [
      "2017-04-01T22:51:50.303Z", 
      "1491087110303", 
      "1491173510303", 
      "group-general-service-mk-threadc", 
      7073, 
      "posted-dev", 
      "1", 
      "NO_METADATA"
    ]
  ]
}
```

The columns and values are separate but how can I combine the columns and values arrays together so that the values have the names with them:

```
{
    [
     {
      "time": "2017-04-01T22:51:50.301Z", 
      "commit_time": "1491087110301", 
      "expiration_time": "1491173510301", 
      "kafka_consumer_group": "group-general-service-master", 
      "kafka_offset_group": 0, 
      "kafka_topic": "replica-conversion-dev", 
      "kafka_topic_partition": "6", 
      "message_metadata": "NO_METADATA"
     }
    ]...     
}
```

Comment: `data.values.map(...` and give it a function that creates an object, iterates the columns array, gives the object a key of the column and a value of the same index from the current value, and then returns the object.

Comment: Just a tip: your *desired* output is not valid.

Comment: The syntax representing the output is messed up, but I'm sure they just meant `[{...}, ...]` They just reversed the bracket styles.

Comment: Unfortunately, they've not shown any attempt to solve the problem, which makes this yet another "question" that treats SO like a code writing service. Too bad since this is really a pretty simple problem to solve.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado thanks for the catch..made and edit to correct that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you need an array of objects, you could iterate the values array and for the keys the columns array and assign the objects to the collecting object. Then return a new array with the objects.

```js
var data = { columns: ["time", "commit_time", "expiration_time", "kafka_consumer_group", "kafka_offset_group", "kafka_topic", "kafka_topic_parition", "message_metadata"], name: "offsets", values: [["2017-04-01T22:51:50.301Z", "1491087110301", "1491173510301", "group-general-service-master", 0, "replica-conversion-dev", "6", "NO_METADATA"], ["2017-04-01T22:51:50.301Z", "1491087110301", "1491173510301", "group-message-service-master", 2, "service-dev", "4", "NO_METADATA"], ["2017-04-01T22:51:50.303Z", "1491087110303", "1491173510303", "group-general-service-mk-threadc", 7073, "posted-dev", "1", "NO_METADATA"]] },
    result = data.values.map(a => Object.assign({}, ...data.columns.map((k, i) => ({ [k]: a[i] }))));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your desired result is not a valid object/array notation.

Assuming you would like to get an array of object, you can try the following:

```
res.values.map(arr => ({
    time: arr[0],
    commit_time: arr[1],
    expiration: arr[2],
    // you get the idea...
}));
```

Or using array destructuring:

```
res.values.map(arr => {
    var obj = {};
    [
        obj.time,
        obj.commit_time,
        obj.expiration,
        // you get the idea...
    ] = arr;
    return obj;
});
```